# Logger for long running python code - Can I use it to monitor status of execution

Tags: python, logging, filehandler

I have a very long running python code that calls multiple api's.

I have also implemented logger at each step to identify the exceptions. But, the FileHandler shows the data only on completion of the python script.

Is there a way to flush the logger after a fixed interval ? I could use it for monitoring the status of the job.

```
# when executed standalone, the main block is called    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Crate logger for RR api application
    logger = logging.getLogger('RR_API')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create file handler which logs messages
    # If the handler is already defined, then no need to set it again
    if not logger.handlers:
        fh = logging.FileHandler("C:///Users///2128///python_data_logger.log")
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    #add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    run_ts = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    logger.info('Starting Time' + '|' + run_ts)
    print ('Starting Time',datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    count = 0
    token = get_temp_token(run_ts)
    portfolio = get_orgs(token,'"https://apidata.ratings.com/v1.0/orgs/"',run_ts)
```

**Output in Log File:**

```
2016-12-30 16:22:01,448 - RR_API - INFO - Starting Time|2016-12-30 16:22:01
2016-12-30 16:22:01,526 - RR_API - CRITICAL - No Access Token was downloaded | 2016-12-30 16:22:01
```

The above lines are visible in log file only when the script execution has terminated.

Comment: Did you wait at the end of the script for some time to make sure the log is actually flushed before executing the script? I am not even seeing the "CRITICAL" message you showed in output in your script. Probably your script is so small and exits fast before you realize the logline is written to the file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The critical message is passed from get_temp_token(run_ts) call. This is to get the access token for the remaining REST calls.